# What is a HPC kernel (MPI-OpenMP)?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmp, cluster-computing, slurm

In plain language, what is a kernel and what it is used for?
I have seen code for parallelization like:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#SBATCH --job-name=bt-mz 
#SBATCH --output=bt-mz_%j.out 
#SBATCH --error=bt-mz_%j.err 
#SBTACH --nodes=1 
#SBATCH --ntasks=12 
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4    
#SBATCH --qos=debug

#MPI + OpenMP 
export NAS_PATH=$HOME/bin 
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

srun $NAS_PATH/bt-mz.C.12 srun $NAS_PATH/sp-mz.C.12
```

Where sp-mz.C.12 and bt-mz.C.12 are called kernels (BT-MZ-MPI SP). What are they?

Comment: This is a highly ambiguous term, and it highly depends on context. It's like asking "what is a node?".

Comment: BT-MZ-MPI SP are apecific kernels as far as I know @Zulan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [benchmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAS_Parallel_Benchmarks) including many components, some of them being related to solving a synthetic system of [nonlinear PDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear#Partial_differential_equations) (BT, SP, LU). Solving such PDEs involves so-called [kernels](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Partial_Differential_Equations/Fundamental_solutions,_Green%27s_functions_and_Green%27s_kernels), that are basically functions with specific properties. Such functions are also used in probability density estimation, signal analysis, etc.

Comment: The Green's kernel analogy seems a bit far fetched to me. I would say we call it a _kernel_ since it is the core of the solution process. That is solving a PDE involves many steps and solving a system of linear algebraic equations is the most computationally intensive part, that David Bailey rightfully called a kernel. In particular, all NAS benchmark programs, not only the ones related to PDEs are kernels.